# Android-Thumbnail showing correct picture but Original showing different Picture

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using camera API in my app now, I have two issues in the app:

1. I am saving the image to a folder in the sdcard, the problem is after capturing and looking to the folder the thumbnail is showing correct image so after selecting the photo it will display previous taken photo in fullscreen.
   Every time I am saving the photo in same name So each time it will overwrite the previous image.
2. Second issue is I am using `params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)` when I press back button the flash doesn't turn of it still remains turn on.I have tried `camera.release()` in the `surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this, but just a rough code to give you the direction.

```
Bitmap bmp;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   //fullscreen 
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

   //set view
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   preview = new Preview(this); // <3>
   rootLayout = ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview));
   rootLayout.addView(preview);
   progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
   ImageView rectView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   rectView.bringToFront();

   buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
   buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) { // <5>
           new connectAsyncTask.execute();
           buttonClick.setEnabled(false);
       }
   });
}
public void comparison(byte[] data,Camera camera) throws IOException
{
   String path=getString(R.string._sdcard_path);//<string name="_sdcard_path">/sdcard/images/</string> 
   String extension=getString(R.string._sdcard_d_jpg);// <string name="_sdcard_d_jpg">.jpg</string>
   /*String srcPath1="/sdcard/images/";
   File f=new File(srcPath1);
   int h=0,count=0;
   String [] cnt=f.list();
       while(h<cnt.length)
       {
           count++;

           h++;
       }extension=count+extension;*/
   ByteArrayOutputStream stream=null;
   FileOutputStream outStream = null;

  bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);


  // int i=0,x=50;

       stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

       temBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, stream);
       path+=String.format(
               getString(R.string._sdcard_d_jpg),
               System.currentTimeMillis());
       outStream = new FileOutputStream(path+extension); // <9>
       outStream.write(stream.toByteArray());
       outStream.close();      
           //rs="Place the strip correctly!!";
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}

// Called when shutter is opened
ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() { // <6>
   @Override
   public void onShutter() {
       Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
   }
};

// Handles data for raw picture
PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() { // <7>
   @Override
   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
       Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
   }
};

// Handles data for jpeg picture
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() { // <8>
   @Override
   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
       try {
           comparison(data,camera);//new connectAsyncTask(data, camera).execute();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }
};



void showProgress() {
   //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Picture is saving please wait..!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   progress.setIndeterminate(true);
   progress.setCancelable(false);
   progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
   progress.show();

}


private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
   // private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

   connectAsyncTask(byte[] data, Camera camera) throws IOException {
       //saveImageToSd(data, camera);

       //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPreExecute();
       showProgress();
   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

       preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
       comparison(data,camera);
       return "";
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       progress.dismiss();
       ImageView rectView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       rectView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

   }

}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

       params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
       camera.setParameters(params);
       if(camera!=null){
           camera.stopPreview();
           camera.release();
               camera = null;
       }
}
```

Comment: @Aaloka just see your previous code and the code that i gave to you compare it and see what changes are required in your code.

Comment: its an override method call automatically when your activity will finish ctrl+space inside activity you can see all the override methods.